# Angular - child component with GET occurs multiple times in parrent component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-components

I have a service which have one GET method for getting list of timezones. This service is used in a child component. Child component is used on a parent component multiple times (parent component has some list of items and if item meets some condition the child component is shown).
The issue is that child components calls the GET multiple times (as many as it is shown on the parent component).
How it should be handled? One solution is calling GET on the parent component and share response with child component, but is there a way to call service  in child component just once and share response with all child components?

// child component

```
import {Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {TimezoneService} from '../../services/timezone.service';
import {shareReplay} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-list',
  templateUrl: './timezone-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timezone-list.component.scss'],
})
export class TimezoneListComponent implements OnInit {
  timezones: any[];

  constructor(private timezoneService: TimezoneService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTimezones();
  }

  getTimezones() {
    return this.timezoneService.getTimezones()
      .pipe(
        shareReplay(1)
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.timezones = response;
        }
      })
  }

}
```

//parent component snippet

```
    <div *ngFor='let item of items; index as $index; trackBy: trackByFn'
         class="d-flex w-100 mb-3">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.type ==='DATE'">
        <child-list></child-list>
      </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use your service, in which you call your GET method. Once you called it, you store the data in your service, and in your child component you can simply get the value.

**service**

```
...
timezones: any[] = null;
...
getTimezones(){
  return this.timezoneService.getTimezones()
  .pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
  ).subscribe((response) => {
    if (response) {
      this.timezones = response;
      this.timezoneService.timezones = response;
    }
  });
}
```

**parent component**

```
...
timezones: any[] = null;

constructor(private timezoneService: TimezoneService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.timezoneService.getTimezones();
}
```

**parent template**

```
<div *ngIf="timezones">
  <div *ngFor='let item of items; index as $index; trackBy: trackByFn' class="d-flex w-100 mb-3">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.type ==='DATE'">
      <child-list></child-list>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you check if your method is done by adding `*ngIf`, so while your method is still doing her job, `*ngIf` will return false, and your child components will not be displayed.

**child component**

```
...
timezones: any[];

constructor(private timezoneService: TimezoneService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.timezones = this.timezoneService.timezones;
}
```

Comment: well, I think it cannot work that way, API calls are asynchronous and this !this.timezoneService.timezones will always be met and thus still multiple calls will be invoked

Comment: No because once you call you method, you will store the data into the timezones variable, so next time you will init a child component, the `!this.timezoneService.timezones` will go to the else part. Even if API calls are asynchronous, you finally get a value, and this value, once it's stored, is just store so not `null` anymore.

Comment: What you can do, as you said, is to call the method from your parent component, and once you stored it into your service, you can call the `*ngFor`. Then in each child you get the value from your service

Comment: thing is that this.timezoneService.timezones = response; is set after call is completed, so for every child component this.timezoneService.timezones is still null

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad. I have edited my post, and added the way I think the best for your issue. You should call your method from your parent, and then from the parent template check if the `timezones` is null or not, this way you can wait to display your childs components.

Comment: yeah, I know that would work but if i want to use child component somewhere else the new parent component would need again call service, right?

Comment: No sure to understand well, your need is that you can call a child component alone from somewhere else or is that you can call another parent component elsewhere, and from this new parent, some child components will be called ?

Comment: I would have at least 2 places with deifferent parent components where I need to use child components, And child components will be shown several times for each and every parent component

Comment: If you need the same `timezones` var in each parent component, just add an if method to check whether the timezones is already set, if not call the method and initiate it, as it was done int eh child component, but this time in the initiation of the parent component.